# Auto position bootstrap dropdown menu in responsive design

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the Bootstrap Dropdown menus in my website. I am aware that I can position where and how the dropdown appears, by adding some classes to the ul, or the container, but is there a way to achieve this positioning automatically?

Let's say for example, that in my site, I have several dropdown menus placed next to each other, and depending on the screen size, the dropdown menus will be pushed down or up by a line or two.

So for example, at a large screen resolution, the dropdowns would look something like this:

> DD1 DD2 DD3 DD4 DD5

While at a smaller screen resolution, they would look like something like this:

> DD1 DD2 DD3
>   DD4 DD5

In this scenario, I can't force neither of the dropdowns, to open to the left, instead of the default right opening, because I wouldn't know the exact position relative to the screen of the dropdowns, so pure CSS won't suffice for my problem.

So my question is:

**Is there a pre-built option in bootstrap.js which positions the opening dropdown correctly in every situation, OR I have to write my own calculations, and use jQuery to achieve the desired result?**